# How to put a DWORD in the registry with the highest bit set

Tags: c#, windows, types, registry

I've run into a strange problem: when setting values of the DWORD type in the Windows Registry from my C# application, I keep getting errors when the highest bit is set. Apparently there seems to be some kind of conversion problem between signed and unsigned integers.

Example: when I do something like this

```
regKey.SetValue("Value", 0x70000000u, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

it works fine. But when I add the highest bit (which, since I'm specifically dealing with unsigned integers, should be just another value bit), like this

```
regKey.SetValue("Value", 0xf0000000u, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

I get an exception ("The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted").

But shouldn't it work? DWORD is an unsigned 32-bit integer data type, and so is the `0xf0000000u` literal (C# automatically assigns it the UInt32 datatype), so they should be a perfect match (and setting the value manually in the registry editor to "0xf0000000" works fine, too). Is this a bug in .NET or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My *guess* is that you need to use a signed `int` instead. So just convert it like this:

```
regKey.SetValue("Value", unchecked((int) 0xf0000000u),
                RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

I agree it's a bit odd, when you consider that DWORD is normally unsigned (IIRC) but it's at least worth a try...

Comment: You're right, it *is* odd, but for what it's worth, it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is crazy late, however, if you don't want to use unchecked or are using VB.Net where it's not available then the following would work as well.

```
Byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(0xf0000000u);
int USignedIntTooBigForInt = BitConverter.ToInt32(byteArray, 0);
regKey.SetValue("Value", USignedIntTooBigForInt, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```