# Windows reads color value from registry wrong

Tags: vb.net, windows, colors

I am writing a `vb.net` program that allows me to set custom default start **ui** colors. I write the colors to the registry this way.

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue( _
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent", _
    "DefaultStartColor", _
    MainForm.btnStartColor.BackColor.GetHashCode.ToString, _
    RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

The code works fine and changes the color. The problem is that the color that windows changes to is different than the code entered in the registry.

**Example:**

If I choose a `yellow` color numbered: `ffffff80` from color dialog control.

It will change the color of `btnStartColor.backcolor` in the program to `yellow` and saves the code to the registry as `ffffff80(4294967168)` but when I log into windows the next time the color windows 8 translates this to is a `baby blue`.

Am I translating it incorrectly or using the wrong color settings?

The funniest thing is that the default color `ff3c3c3c(4282137660)` works fine and shows up as the correct `grey color`.

Here is a test code I made to describe this issue better:

```
Dim BC As String = MainForm.btnStartColor.BackColor.ToArgb
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue( _
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent", _
    "StartColor", BC, RegistryValueKind.DWord)

MainForm.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml( _
    My.Computer.Registry.GetValue( _
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent", _
    "StartColor", Nothing))
```

this code will make the background of my program's main form the correct color but windows start ui is shows another color. 
ex. if I enter orange the registry DWORD is 0xffff8000(4294934528) Windows Start ui shows a blue color

Comment: Note that this registry key is not documented and may change at any time. Make sure your customers understand this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you believe `GetHashCode` returns the correct byte order that windows is looking for?

If `0xFFFFFF80` result in a blue, then the correct byte order is most likely `ABGR`.

You can create the correct value like this:

```
uint V = (((((0xFFu << 8) | c.B) << 8) | c.G) << 8) | c.R;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of code this is but it's not recognized as vb.net in vs 2012 . but this order did not work either. The order I got was figured from both the default code in the registry and what little info I found on the net.

Comment: I take that back I did figure out that it was c# and tried to convert it. but the registry will not accept uint as a dword value So I' Am Attempting convertions of it

Comment: Ok the code you suggest also results in the wrong color when windows pulls the info from the registry. However when I pull the info from the registry and use it in my program to make the background color of the form change it works fine. Why is windows 8 using it differently

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608400/how-to-put-a-dword-in-the-registry-with-the-highest-bit-set

Comment: No luck there either Rotem. Did you notice I put some test code above. that's where I'm at now.