# How do I set registry QWORD to max value and retreive it programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, registry

Should I be able to programmatically set a Registry QWORD value to UInt64.MaxValue, and a DWORD valaue to UInt32.MaxValue?

I've spent a couple hours and haven't figured out the proper way to set or get a registry QWORD.  The Max Value of a QWORD should be UInt64.MaxValue or FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, correct?  That's what RegEdit lets me set it to, but I can't set the value using Microsoft's example or any other examples of setting registry values.

I also have a problem with DWORD, I have a problem setting the value but have a workaround for retrieving it.

```
            // Create HKCU\RegistryValueKind key
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("RegistryValueKindExample");


        // This sets DWORD registry value to 7FFFFFFF instead of FFFFFFFF
        rk.SetValue("DWordValue", Int32.MaxValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord);

        // This sets QWORD registry value to 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF instead of FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        rk.SetValue("QuadWordValue", Int64.MaxValue, RegistryValueKind.QWord);



        // Unsigned UInt32 would be great for setting DWORD to max value...
        Console.WriteLine("UInt32.MaxValue=" + UInt32.MaxValue.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("UInt32.MaxValue(Hex)=" + UInt32.MaxValue.ToString("X"));
        // But this line craps out: System.ArgumentException: 'The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted.'
        //rk.SetValue("DWordValue", UInt32.MaxValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord); 


        // UInt64 would be great for setting QWORD to max value...
        Console.WriteLine("UInt64.MaxValue=" + UInt64.MaxValue.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("UInt64.MaxValue(Hex)=" + UInt64.MaxValue.ToString("X"));
        // But this line craps out: Same error as setting DWORD value to UInt32.MaxValue
        rk.SetValue("QuadWordValue", UInt64.MaxValue, RegistryValueKind.QWord);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a DWORD in the registry with the highest bit set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608400/how-to-put-a-dword-in-the-registry-with-the-highest-bit-set)

Comment: That helped with setting the value, I still cannot get the value.

Comment: Well it is just a straight forward of writing: `rk.SetValue( "QuadWordValue", unchecked((Int64)UInt64.MaxValue),RegistryValueKind.QWord );` and `UInt64 qwordv = unchecked((UInt64)(Int64)rk.GetValue( "QuadWordValue" ));` - The c# registry api uses **signed** values and you have to manage the cast by yourself. Cast `object` to `Int64` to `UInt64`

Comment: Please do **not** update your question into an answer. Please respect that you are on a Question&Answer site. It is fine if you answer your own question, but use the answer section below your question

Comment: Thanks I figured out a nastier way to do it took twice as many lines :)  I'll update with your correct way.

Comment: I made a rollback to your question and you can add your solution as an answer and accept it (after some time)

Comment: OK, thanks for the help!